# Javascript If/Else & setAttribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

Just as a heads up, I'm very much a beginner so before thinking too much about why I'm doing what I'm doing in this particular way, I just wanted to clear up that I'm just practicing and trying to get a grasp on what I can and can't do, writing functions, and using methods. Of course, I'm open to suggestion I just don't want anyone to get too caught up in the fact that I'm doing something in what might not be the best way. On to the question.

In summary, I'm trying to write some JS to swap CSS files to change themes on a website.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div onclick="swapStyleSheet('css/styles-black.css')" class="onoffswitch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
  <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch"></label>
</div>
```

The following code seems to work:

```
function swapStyleSheet(sheet){
  if  (document.getElementById('pagestyle').getAttribute('href') == "css/styles-white.css") {
    document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', "css/styles-black.css");
  }
}
```

I'll note that this works whether I set "css/styles-black.css" directly or pass the argument through the function call (as can be seen in the HTML).

To switch back from styles-black.css to styles-white.css, I've added an else statement:

```
function swapStyleSheet(sheet){
  if  (document.getElementById('pagestyle').getAttribute('href') == "css/styles-white.css") {
    document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', "css/styles-black.css");
  } else {
    document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', "css/styles-white.css");
  }
}
```

This does not work and I'm trying to figure out why. By default, it is set to use the styles-white.css style. What am I missing? I feel like it's one of those small things that's easy [for a beginner] to overlook.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code seems ok
1. Are you sure there is a stylesheet called styles-white?
2. Why are you trying to change it black if the default is white? Wouldn't it make more sense if you added the function to a button?
3. Are you sure you are calling the function? Would need to see the rest of the code.

Comment: Please give a read of how to create a [mcve]. There's no way to diagnose this without knowing the HTML this JavaScript is acting upon. Also, you say it "does not work", but what does that mean? What are you expecting to happen? What happens instead? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? I see none.

Comment: Just a piece of advice:  learn to use `===` instead of `==`.  :)

Comment: What's the `sheet` parameter for?

Comment: I added the HTML to my example (sorry, I totally forgot to add that).

Comment: @BobbyJack I intended to pass in the href value for use with the setAttribute part of the code. It was initially document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);. This worked, btw.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I added the HTML for clarity. What it basically does is create a toggle-switch. I won't include all the CSS for that switch but the switch does move and change colors when clicked as expected. I'm including the JS because I want to swap stylesheets when the switch is clicked. If I just use the first bit of code (excluding the else statements), it works. It changes to styles-black.css. What I need it to do now is go back to styles-white.css when clicked again. It does not. The toggle switch behaves as if there's no JS there at all. No errors are produced.

Comment: @andross Yes. styles-white.css is the default sheet that I'm calling and using in the <head>. styles-black.css is a nearly identical sheet save for changing the background from white to black so I can identify the change. They exist in the same directory. The function is attached to some HTML (I've updated my submission to include this HTML). If I remove the else statement, it works just fine, switching from styles-white to styles-black. I need to be able to switch back from styles-black to styles-white, hense the ELSE, and with this added even just the IF statement fails. No errors produced.

Comment: The code can be improved (a lot) but I can't see why it wouldn't work. Can you put everything together in a `jsFiddle` to demonstrate it?

Comment: You don't have the `anchor` tag in your markup.

Comment: It's working to me at link http://codepen.io/bra1N/pen/zBWQKa . Inspect and wath "pagestyle" id.

Comment: It's working as it is, but here's a _shorter_ version: https://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/11o0rrv0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this work with jQuery:

```
$(".onoffswitch").click(function(){
    if($('.onoffswitch-checkbox').is(':checked') == false) {
        $("#pagestyle").attr("href", "css/styles-black.css");
    } else if ($('.onoffswitch-checkbox').is(':checked') == true) {
        $("#pagestyle").attr("href", "css/styles-white.css");
    }
})
```

I was also able to make it work a different way to be a little less specific about the href, as I realize not every page would be located in such a manner that css/styles-white.css would be appropriate:

```
$(".onoffswitch").click(function(){
    if($('.onoffswitch-checkbox').is(':checked') == false) {            
        $("#pagestyle").attr('href', function(i, blackCSS) {
            return blackCSS.replace('white', 'black');                
        });            
    } 
});
```

I would still like to figure out how to get this to work with vanilla JS. I'm sure it's something I'm doing wrong. I was very glad to have been able to work out some sort of solution though,